# How to structure React code with Apollo Query so that a random queried array of objects doesn't rerender with state change?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

**The problem**:  I'm using Apollo Client, and have the deck rendered like this "/deck/2" and I want to randomly shuffle the cards, and display just one at a time with a button to view the next.  I keep running in the problem with React re-rendering everytime the state is changed (my onClick index counter +1), which reshuffles the cards since the shuffledCards variable is inside the query.  I'm not sure how to prevent this from happening.

How can I shuffle the list without worrying about them being reshuffled 'onClick' of the button.  I imagine there is a way to get the randomized array outside of the render, which I can do in Regular react, but using Apollo queries I'm stumbling to understand.

This is where I am stumbling due to my inexperience in React and Graphql with Apollo, and I haven't found a similar Apollo graphql project to lean off of.  I can't use map on an object, but maybe there is a way to use map to display 1 object of the array at a time?  I haven't found a working solution.

**What I intend to have happen**: I simply want to render the shuffled array of cards one at a time, and pressing the next button should step through the cards in the randomized array, without re-rendering whenever I click the button, otherwise cards will be repeated at random.

Here's the code:

````
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
    ```
    import CardItem from "./CardItem";

    const CARDS_QUERY = gql`
      query CardsQuery($id: ID!) {
        ```
    `;

    export class Cards extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          index: 0
        };

        this.goToNext = this.goToNext.bind(this);
      }

      goToNext() {
        this.setState({
          index: this.state.index + 1
        });
      }

      shuffle(array) {
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
          [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
        }
        return array;
      }

      render() {
        let { id } = this.props.match.params;
        id = parseInt(id);

        return (
          <Fragment>
            <Query query={CARDS_QUERY} variables={{ id }}>
              {({ data, error, loading }) => {
                if (loading) {
                  return <Loading />;
                }
                if (error)
                }

                const CardsToRender = data.deck.cards;

                //This variable gets reshuffled at every re-render
                const shuffledCards = this.shuffle(CardsToRender);

                //Single item to be returned
                const item = shuffledCards[this.state.index];

                if (this.state.index >= shuffledCards.length) {
                  return (
                    <div>
                      <h1>Finished</h1>
                    </div>
                  );
                } else {
                  return (
                    <Fragment>
               // Here I can get one item to display, but if I press next, the state changes which fires a re-render, 
           //shuffling the cards once more.  My intention is to only shuffle cards at first render until the browser page is
           //refreshed or user navigates away
              <h1>{item.front}</h1>
              <h1>{item.back}</h1>

                   //My second attempt is to map out the cards, but I have only been able to render a list,
                  // but not one at a time.  Maybe there is a simple code solution in my .map to display
                    //one at a time without needing to change state?
                      {shuffledCards.map(card => (
                        <CardItem key={card.id} card={card} />
                      ))}
                      <p>
                        <button onClick={this.goToNext}>Next</button>
                      </p>
                    </Fragment>
                  );
                }
              }}
            </Query>
          </Fragment>
        );
      }
    }

    ```
````

I'll be grateful for any help provided.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of Appolo Query but the issue you mentioned is more related to React. You can try below one to avoid shuffling cards on each re-render.

Refactor your component into two parts.

1) ShuffleCards.js(give any name as you like :) ) - Move your  component into "ShuffleCards" and pass shuffled cords to the child component where you can update the state to render the next card.

// ShuffledCards.js

````
 import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
    ```
    import CardItem from "./CardItem";

    const CARDS_QUERY = gql`
      query CardsQuery($id: ID!) {
        ```
    `;

    export class ShuffleCards extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      shuffle(array) {
        for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
          const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
          [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
        }
        return array;
      }

      render() {
        let { id } = this.props.match.params;
        id = parseInt(id);
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <Query query={CARDS_QUERY} variables={{ id }}>
              {({ data, error, loading }) => {
                if (loading) {
                  return <Loading />;
                }
                if (error) {
                }
                const CardsToRender = data.deck.cards;
                const shuffledCards = this.shuffle(CardsToRender);
                return (
                    <Cards shuffledCards={shuffledCards} /> 
                );
              }}
            </Query>
          </Fragment>
        );
      }
    }
````

Move the code which handles the displaying card and updating the state to the "Cards" component.

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import CardItem from "./CardItem";

export class Cards extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          index: 0
        };

        this.goToNext = this.goToNext.bind(this);
      }

      goToNext() {
        this.setState({
          index: this.state.index + 1
        });
      }

    render() {
    const {shuffledCards} = this.props || [];
    return (
        <div>
        {
            this.state.index >= shuffledCards.length ?
              <div>
                <h1>Finished</h1>
              </div>
              :
              <Fragment>
                  <h1>{item.front}</h1>
                  <h1>{item.back}</h1>
                  {
                      shuffledCards.map(card => (
                      <CardItem key={card.id} card={card} />
                      ))
                  }
                  <p>
                  <button onClick={this.goToNext}>Next</button>
                  </p>
              </Fragment>
        }
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling this.shuffle() in your render function - therefore it will shuffle on each render.

Move that to your constructor and it will only get called once.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    index: 0
  };

  this.goToNext = this.goToNext.bind(this);
  const CardsToRender = data.deck.cards;
}
```